# an image wont show, with correct path

Tags: html, image, url

I get some image from my local server and display it in an `img` tag

```
<img src="myurl"></img>
```

the problem that the url is correct but the image does not display. I chmod it to 777. But is still not display.. Why ?

Edit : myurl is something like `/Users/home/Desktop/Sites/app/public/files/campaign/image/originals/273/Capture‌​.png`

Comment: What is the value of myurl ?

Comment: @PatsyIssa `myurl` is some `myhome_path/myapp_path/myfile`

Comment: Give us a rendered code output, like (https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f01b49db716cde6fbec9d43b1f15c0f1?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG)

Comment: @PatsyIssa, I don't really understand. It looks like `/Users/home/Desktop/Sites/app/public/files/campaign/image/originals/273/Capture.png`

Answer (score 1):

> 1.open your webpage in mozilla.
>   2.inspect element with firebug.
>   3.Just hover over your img src code..
>   4.If image is displaying there when you hover then have to fix in the layout.
>   5.If it doesnot display when you hover,then you have to correct your image path..

Comment: really weird, I took the same path in my console and I opened the image from there, and it worked !

Comment: Can you paste your code along with your question,so that can frame what hits the error..

Comment: NO it doesn't. And what is weird is that I changed my `url` to a relative one, and it worked !!!

Comment: Then the thing is you are missing your path for that image..Try to give proper path for that image else try some editors,drag and drop your image,exact path will be quoted..

Comment: really weird, I put the exact same path in my browser and it opened it jsut well !!!

Comment: try to place that image within your project folder and pass the url.It will work...From the above code i think you are displaying an image from folders reside in desktop.Dont do that.